# Drop shadow in the wrong place when hovering translated clip-path polygons

Tags: css, clip-path, css-filters

I have a list of 3 triangles, to which one I want to apply a drop-shadow when hovering over it. The last 2 triangles are translated so that they stand side-by-side. When I hover over the box of the 1st triangle (the green one in the snippet), the drop-shadow appears under the last triangle. Why does that happen, what could I do to avoid this? And why is the 1st triangle registering the hover event on the whole box and not just on the triangle?

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.one {
  background-color: green;
}

.two {
  background-color: blue;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.three {
  background-color: red;
  transform: translateX(200%);
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5))
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="one"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="two"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="three"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because you are applying the `drop-shadow` to the `li` and you are translating the div inside. So when hovering the first `li` you will be hovering over the last `li` since this one comes later in the DOM tree.

Add some border to better see the issue. You can clearly see that all the `li` are stacked above each other. So hovering all of them will trigger the hover on the last one.

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border:2px solid; 
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.one {
  background-color: green;
}

.two {
  background-color: blue;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.three {
  background-color: red;
  transform: translateX(200%);
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  border:2px solid green; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="one"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="two"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="three"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can translate the `li` instead and avoid this issue:

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.one {
  background-color: green;
}

.two {
  background-color: blue;
}

.three {
  background-color: red;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateX(200%);
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5))
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="one"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="two"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="three"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you want to hover only the triangle, simply make the height of the `li` to be `0` thus only the child element will trigger the hover which is your triangle element:

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:0;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.one {
  background-color: green;
}

.two {
  background-color: blue;
}

.three {
  background-color: red;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateX(200%);
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5))
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="one"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="two"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="three"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is there a way then to register the hover event only inside of the triangle and not the whole box?